# How can I trace an event using Firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

For instance when I inspect the element, I want to know all events bound to an element..Where can I find these?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960709/inspect-an-element-to-investigate-jquery-event-bindings

Answer (score 3):

I asked a [related question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045169/how-can-i-find-what-onchange-function-an-element-has), and got this answer:

You can see the jquery expression in firebug DOM inspector using **FireQuery** in firefox 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firequery/

It worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Visual Event bookmarklet at:
http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

It overlays some icons representing each event that is attached to DOM items and you can quickly inspect the event's code by clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 2):

There's Firebug extension [Eventbug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug).

> Eventbug is a Firebug extension that lists all of the event handlers
>   on the page grouped by event type...

---

In Chrome's Developer Tools there is **Event Listeners** tab in the **Elements** panel, which lists all listeners attached to an element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download fireQuery. Its a firebug addon that shows you any event that is bound to an element as well as any .data that maybe assigned to that element

Answer (score 0):

try http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug