# click event not working on dynamically inserted element in chrome(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I do here is that I dynamically create a drop-down and bind the `click` event to the `<option>` within the `<select>`

```
var $select = $('<select></select>'),
    $option1 = $('<option>a</option>'),
    $option2 = $('<option>b</option>');

    $option1.val(1);
    $option2.val(2);

$(document.body).on('click','select option',function(){
      console.log("click-option works");
    });

    $select.append($option1);
    $select.append($option2);

    $(document.body).append($select);
```

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements), Since I am dynamically adding content, I delegated the event handling to the top most element in the DOM.

Now my problem is this is not working in chrome as expected. In fire-fox it seems to work fine.

I have also read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323944/click-event-is-not-delegated-in-chrome) link and the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537323/jquery-function-not-binding-to-newly-added-dom-elements) one but to no avail.

Interestingly when I do this in the place of `'select option'` selector

```
$(document.body).on('click','select',function(){
      console.log("click-option works");
    });
```

The output is logged, However that is definitely not what I had in mind. The output is logged whenever I select the drop-down itself, not to mention the options in the drop-down. As a temporary work around I am using `change` event in the following way :

```
$(document.body).on('change','select',function(event){
      console.log("change works");
      console.log(event);
    });
```

This seems to do the trick,However I want to know why It is not working in the original case and any work-arounds if possible.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cspvyym3/6/) for what I have done so far.

UPDATE : I have also checked out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome). However that is for just pure javascript, I wanted to know why it snot working in my case. More specifically, in the delegated event handler where we specifiy the selector, Why does it fail at `'select option'` and work at `'select'` in chrome ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Comment: Yes I had checked that out , but isin't that a pure javascript thing. I thought jQuery was designed to smoothen such stuff out

Comment: yes the events at the lowest level are pure js, but each browser handles these events differently. Webkit (chrome) seems to have this ongoing issue

Comment: okay that seems to explain a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attaching a `click` event to the `option` elements which isn't very reliable. The `click` event should go on the `select` itself - but note that even that isn't following best practices as you should use the `change` event so that your code is fired even when the option is selected via the keyboard. To get the value of the selected ooption within the handler use `$(this).val()`, like this:

```js
var $select = $('<select></select>'),
  $option1 = $('<option>a</option>'),
  $option2 = $('<option>b</option>');

$option1.val(1);
$option2.val(2);

$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$select.append($option1);
$select.append($option2);

$('body').append($select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that this can be shortened to just:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('<select><option value="1">a</option><option value="2">b</option></select>').appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input  I am already doing that for now as I mentioned in the question. Now is there any way I can extract from change as to which option was originally selected. That was my motivation to use click actually ?

Comment: Yes, you can just use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the selected option in the `change` event handler

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Also as mentioned in the comments by @ben sewards, It's specifically a  web-kit issue, would it be possible to expand on that in the answer ?

Comment: It's not just a Webkit issue, it also affects older versions of Mozilla and IE. This is why I stated that it's unreliable to use that event on the `option` element